# Pagination not showing correct number of items

Tags: magento2, pagination

I have this **block** with **pagination**:

```
        protected function _prepareLayout()
        {
            parent::_prepareLayout();
            $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Table'));


            if ($this->getItem()) {
                $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                    'Module.pagination.pagination.pager'
                )->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10,15=>15,50=>50,100=>100))->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
                    $this->getItem()
                );

                $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
                $this->getItem()->load();
            }

            return $this;

        }
        public function getItem()
        {
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $attributeSetCollectionFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory');
            /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\Collection $attributeSetCollection */
            $attributeSetCollection = $attributeSetCollectionFactory->create();
            $attributeSets = $attributeSetCollection->getItems();

            return $attributeSetCollection;
        }

        public function getPagerHtml()
        {
            return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
        }


    }
```

And in my **template** I have this under the **table**:

```
 <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

THE PROBLEM IS:

I have **18 items** in my table, but I set to show only **10 per page**, but, nothings happen, the page reload, but continue **showing 10**. what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I remove the set size and continue the same issue

Comment: I think you should remove this `$attributeSetCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $attributeSetCollection->setCurPage($page);` from your `getItem` method and let the pagination work it's magic.

Comment: i removed, and run cache flush and clean, and continue the same, and i dont understand why :(